# Meteor Updating a nested property on a collection object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Say I have a document like this:

```
{
    _id: kjakldjflkajda
    property: value
    nest: [
    {
       one: 1
       two: 2
    },
    {
       one: 2
       two: 3
    }
    ]
}
```

How do I update the nested one property from 2 to 3 without changing the other property from 1 to 3

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
MyCollection.update({ _id: 'kjakldjflkajda' }, { $set: { 'nest.0.one': 3 } });
```

Comment: There's a better way to do without hard coding the index to update. But the question has been asked many times before.

Comment: @NeilLunn Yes, it was probably asked before. I am totally aware of "other methods", but this one is the simplest and whether "other method" are "better" probably depends on the specific use case.

Comment: What If I want change all elements in the array? is it `'nest.$.one'` ?